# How to default the selector in web scraping in r?

Tags: r, database, web-scraping, selector, rvest

I am extracting information on different topics from specific objects. In the first part, when I wrote the code, the selectors provided the specific information I was looking for. However, each object provides less or more information. The fact is that the end result is a matrix with many NA values ​​and information in the wrong order. I checked it the page and the selectors in some objects provide some information and in another object the info is different.

There is a way to use the name of the variable upside of the desired selector with the goal to obtain default information without matter the changes due to website or information length.

The first part (vector `Var`), was obtained with a previous process

```r
Var <- c("https://eol.org/pages/401504/data",  "https://eol.org/pages/3089826/data",
         "https://eol.org/pages/52361/data",   "https://eol.org/pages/2967667/data",
         "https://eol.org/pages/587416/data",  "https://eol.org/pages/3096662/data",
         "https://eol.org/pages/3096667/data", "https://eol.org/pages/18009694/data", 
         "https://eol.org/pages/2967662/data", "https://eol.org/pages/2967669/data")
```

This is my code:

```r
GiveMeData<-function(url){ 

  furl<-read_html(url)

  iden<-"body > div.l-basic-main > div.l-tabs > div > div > div.names-wrapper > div.names > h1 > i"
  Iden<-html_node(furl,iden)
  Identext<-html_text(Iden)

  dmin<-"body > div.l-basic-main > div.l-content > div > div.l-below-filters > ul > li:nth-child(25) > div.trait-data > div.trait-val"
  Dmin<-html_node(furl,dmin)
  Dmintext<-html_text(Dmin)

  dmax<-"body > div.l-basic-main > div.l-content > div > div.l-below-filters > ul > li:nth-child(24) > div.trait-data > div.trait-val"
  Dmax<-html_node(furl,dmax)
  Dmaxtext<-html_text(Dmax)

  dminextra<-"body > div.l-basic-main > div.l-content > div > div.l-below-filters > ul > li:nth-child(24) > div.trait-data > div.trait-val"
  Dminesxtra<-html_node(furl,dminextra)
  Dminextratext<-html_text(Dmin)

  dmaxextra<-"body > div.l-basic-main > div.l-content > div > div.l-below-filters > ul > li:nth-child(27) > div.trait-data > div.trait-val"
  Dmaxesxtra<-html_node(furl,dmaxextra)
  Dmaxextratext<-html_text(Dmax)

  #Temperature
  tmin<-"body > div.l-basic-main > div.l-content > div > div.l-below-filters > ul > li:nth-child(38) > div.trait-data > div.trait-val"
  Tmin<-html_node(furl,tmin)
  Tmintext<-html_text(Tmin)

  tmax<-"body > div.l-basic-main > div.l-content > div > div.l-below-filters > ul > li:nth-child(54) > div.trait-data > div.trait-val"
  Tmax<-html_node(furl,tmax)
  Tmaxtext<-html_text(Tmax)

  tminextra<-"body > div.l-basic-main > div.l-content > div > div.l-below-filters > ul > li:nth-child(53) > div.trait-data > div.trait-val"
  Tminextra<-html_node(furl,tminextra)
  Tminextratext<-html_text(Tminextra)

  tmaxextra<-"body > div.l-basic-main > div.l-content > div > div.l-below-filters > ul > li:nth-child(52) > div.trait-data > div.trait-val"
  Tmaxextra<-html_node(furl,tmaxextra)
  Tmaxextratext<-html_text(Tmaxextra)

  Identext

  Tmaxtext<-gsub("degrees Celsius\n","",Tmaxtext)
  Tmaxtext<-gsub("\n","", Tmaxtext)


  Tmintext<-gsub("degrees Celsius\n","",Tmintext)
  Tmintext<-gsub("\n","", Tmintext)


  Tmaxextratext<-gsub("degrees Celsius\n","",Tmaxextratext)
  Tmaxextratext<-gsub("\n","", Tmaxextratext)

  Tminextratext<-gsub("degrees Celsius\n","",Tminextratext)
  Tminextratext<-gsub("\n","",Tminextratext)

  Dmaxtext<-gsub(" m\n","",Dmaxextratext)
  Dmaxtext<-gsub("\n","",Dmaxextratext)

  Dmintext<-gsub(" m\n","",Dmintext)
  Dmintext<-gsub("\n","",Dmintext)

  Dmaxextratext<-gsub(" m\n","",Dmaxextratext)
  Dmaxextratext<-gsub("\n","",Dmaxextratext)

  Dminextratext<-gsub(" m\n","",Dminextratext)
  Dminextratext<-gsub("\n","",Dminextratext)

  info=(c(as.character(Identext), as.character(Tmaxtext), as.character(Tmintext), as.character(Tminextratext), as.character(Dmaxtext), as.character(Dmaxextratext), as.character(Dminextratext)))

}


output2<- lapply(c(Var), function(x) tryCatch(GiveMeData(x), error = function(e){}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data on these different web pages are in no definite order, and they are in html tags which do not have standard labels. Some fields have multiple entries, and some have missing entries. There is therefore no way for you to select the data you want by defaulting css selectors. You need a different method.

The key to this is realising that each data entry is self-contained, and that the text can act as labels. You can therefore build a data frame containing each entry on the page. For numeric values, you can extract the number and get maximum / minimum values for fields with multiple entries.

I have changed your `GiveMeData` function to do this:

```r
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

GiveMeData <- function(url)
{ 
  # Define some strings that we will use to find the nodes and parse strings
  number_regex   <- "-?[[:digit:]]+[.]*[[:digit:]]{0,10}"
  species_xpath  <- "//div[@class='names']//i"
  genus_xpath    <- "//div[@class='names']/h1"
  all_data_xpath <- "//div[@class='trait-data']"

  # Read the page using rvest
  furl    <- read_html(url)

  # Read the species name. If there isn't one, just get the genus
  species <- html_nodes(furl, xpath = species_xpath) %>% html_text()
  if(length(species) == 0)
  {
    species <- html_nodes(furl, xpath = genus_xpath) %>% html_text()
  }

  # Get an entry for each data element and parse the text into a two-column
  # data frame with the label and the data content
  html_nodes(furl, xpath = all_data_xpath) %>% 
  html_text()                              %>%
  strsplit("\n\n")                         %>% 
  lapply(function(x) 
           {
             x[which(x != "" & !grepl("URI:", x))]
           }
         )                                 %>%
  lapply(function(x) 
           {
             values <- paste0(x[-1], collapse = " ");
             values <- gsub("\n", "", values);
             values <- gsub(" ([(]m(in|ax)[)])", "", values)
             data.frame(label = x[1], value = values, stringsAsFactors = F)
           }
         )                                 %>%
  {do.call("rbind", .)}                     ->
  df

  # extract the numbers from the value field
  gregexpr(number_regex, df$value) %>%
  {regmatches(df$value, .)}        %>%
  lapply( function(x) 
            if(length(x) > 0) 
              as.numeric(x[1]) 
            else NA)               %>%
  unlist -> df$number

  # Now remove numbers and terminal spaces from the "value" fields
  df$value                     %<>% 
  {gsub(number_regex, "", .)}  %>% 
  {gsub("(^ +)|( +$)", "", .)}

  # Finally, create a data frame with only one entry for each label, taking
  # max / min values for the numeric entries
  lapply(split.data.frame(df, df$label), 
         function(x)
         {
            data.frame(species = species,
                       measure = x$label[1], 
                       min = min(x$number), 
                       max = max(x$number),
                       value = x$value[1], 
                       stringsAsFactors = F)
           }
         )                            %>% 
  {do.call("rbind", .)}               %>% 
  `row.names<-.data.frame`(1:nrow(.)) %>%
  as_tibble()                         %>%
  return()
}
```

Now when you call:

```r
output2 <- lapply(c(Var), function(x) tryCatch(GiveMeData(x), error = function(e){}))
```

You get this value for output2:

```r
output2
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 15 x 5
#>    species            measure                         min     max value            
#>    <chr>              <chr>                         <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>            
#>  1 Bispira melanosti~ body length                 100     100     mm               
#>  2 Bispira melanosti~ ecomorphological guild       NA      NA     planktonic       
#>  3 Bispira melanosti~ geographic distribution in~  NA      NA     South Atlantic   
#>  4 Bispira melanosti~ habitat is                   NA      NA     marine benthic b~
#>  5 Bispira melanosti~ latitude                      7.24   30.3   degrees          
#>  6 Bispira melanosti~ longitude                   -97.6    93.7   degrees          
#>  7 Bispira melanosti~ trophic guild                NA      NA     suspension feeder
#>  8 Bispira melanosti~ water depth                   0.9    75     m                
#>  9 Bispira melanosti~ water dissolved O2 concent~   4.54    4.87  mL/L             
#> 10 Bispira melanosti~ water nitrate concentration   1.35    2.93  µmol/L           
#> 11 Bispira melanosti~ water O2 saturation          87.2    97.4   percent          
#> 12 Bispira melanosti~ water phosphate concentrat~   0.129   0.354 µmol/L           
#> 13 Bispira melanosti~ water salinity               36.3    36.4   PSU              
#> 14 Bispira melanosti~ water silicate concentrati~   1.49    2.17  µmol/L           
#> 15 Bispira melanosti~ water temperature            20.5    24.6   degrees Celsius  
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    species        measure                 min   max value                          
#>    <chr>          <chr>                 <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                          
#>  1 Branchiomma b~ body length           100   100   mm                             
#>  2 Branchiomma b~ ecomorphological gui~  NA    NA   planktonic                     
#>  3 Branchiomma b~ geographic distribut~  NA    NA   Coral Sea                      
#>  4 Branchiomma b~ habitat                NA    NA   marine                         
#>  5 Branchiomma b~ habitat is             NA    NA   marine benthic biome           
#>  6 Branchiomma b~ introduced range inc~  NA    NA   Spanish Exclusive Economic Zon~
#>  7 Branchiomma b~ invasive in            NA    NA   Cyprus                         
#>  8 Branchiomma b~ latitude               18.2  23.9 degrees                        
#>  9 Branchiomma b~ longitude             -97.8 -90.7 degrees                        
#> 10 Branchiomma b~ trophic guild          NA    NA   suspension feeder              
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#>   species     measure                          min   max value                     
#>   <chr>       <chr>                          <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                     
#> 1 Branchiomma body length                      100   100 mm                        
#> 2 Branchiomma ecomorphological guild            NA    NA planktonic                
#> 3 Branchiomma feeding structure                 NA    NA buccal organ absent or oc~
#> 4 Branchiomma geographic distribution inclu~    NA    NA Red Sea                   
#> 5 Branchiomma habitat is                        NA    NA marine benthic biome      
#> 6 Branchiomma marine larval development str~    NA    NA maternally derived nutrit~
#> 7 Branchiomma pattern of oogenesis              NA    NA extraovarian              
#> 8 Branchiomma trophic guild                     NA    NA suspension feeder         
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> # A tibble: 9 x 5
#>   species              measure                          min   max value            
#>   <chr>                <chr>                          <dbl> <dbl> <chr>            
#> 1 Branchiomma luculla~ body length                   100    100   mm               
#> 2 Branchiomma luculla~ ecomorphological guild         NA     NA   planktonic       
#> 3 Branchiomma luculla~ geographic distribution incl~  NA     NA   English Channel  
#> 4 Branchiomma luculla~ habitat is                     NA     NA   marine benthic b~
#> 5 Branchiomma luculla~ latitude                       30.6   50.8 degrees          
#> 6 Branchiomma luculla~ longitude                      -4.14  32.3 degrees          
#> 7 Branchiomma luculla~ pattern of oogenesis           NA     NA   extraovarian     
#> 8 Branchiomma luculla~ substrate type                 NA     NA   bedrock          
#> 9 Branchiomma luculla~ trophic guild                  NA     NA   suspension feeder
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> # A tibble: 22 x 5
#>    species         measure                       min   max value                   
#>    <chr>           <chr>                       <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                   
#>  1 Branchiomma bo~ body size                    50    50   mm                      
#>  2 Branchiomma bo~ ecomorphological guild       NA    NA   planktonic              
#>  3 Branchiomma bo~ ecosystem engineering        NA    NA   organism is an ecosyste~
#>  4 Branchiomma bo~ feeding structure            NA    NA   buccal organ absent or ~
#>  5 Branchiomma bo~ geographic distribution in~  NA    NA   Skagerrak               
#>  6 Branchiomma bo~ habitat is                   NA    NA   caves                   
#>  7 Branchiomma bo~ latitude                     36.6  80.7 degrees                 
#>  8 Branchiomma bo~ locomotion                   NA    NA   non-motile / semi-motile
#>  9 Branchiomma bo~ longitude                   -20    57.8 degrees                 
#> 10 Branchiomma bo~ marine larval development ~  NA    NA   maternally derived nutr~
#> # ... with 12 more rows
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   species           measure                           min   max value              
#>   <chr>             <chr>                           <dbl> <dbl> <chr>              
#> 1 Branchiomma picta body length                       100   100 mm                 
#> 2 Branchiomma picta ecomorphological guild             NA    NA planktonic         
#> 3 Branchiomma picta geographic distribution includ~    NA    NA Seto Inland Sea    
#> 4 Branchiomma picta habitat is                         NA    NA marine benthic bio~
#> 5 Branchiomma picta trophic guild                      NA    NA suspension feeder  
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   species              measure                  min   max value               
#>   <chr>                <chr>                  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>               
#> 1 Branchiomma wyvillei body length              100   100 mm                  
#> 2 Branchiomma wyvillei ecomorphological guild    NA    NA planktonic          
#> 3 Branchiomma wyvillei habitat is                NA    NA marine benthic biome
#> 4 Branchiomma wyvillei trophic guild             NA    NA suspension feeder   
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   species                 measure                       min   max value            
#>   <chr>                   <chr>                       <dbl> <dbl> <chr>            
#> 1 Branchiomma nigromacul~ body length                   100   100 mm               
#> 2 Branchiomma nigromacul~ ecomorphological guild         NA    NA planktonic       
#> 3 Branchiomma nigromacul~ geographic distribution in~    NA    NA South Atlantic   
#> 4 Branchiomma nigromacul~ habitat is                     NA    NA marine benthic b~
#> 5 Branchiomma nigromacul~ trophic guild                  NA    NA suspension feeder
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#>   species         measure                 min   max value                          
#>   <chr>           <chr>                 <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                          
#> 1 Branchiomma bo~ body length             100   100 mm                             
#> 2 Branchiomma bo~ ecomorphological gui~    NA    NA planktonic                     
#> 3 Branchiomma bo~ geographic distribut~    NA    NA Israeli part of the Mediterran~
#> 4 Branchiomma bo~ habitat                  NA    NA marine                         
#> 5 Branchiomma bo~ habitat is               NA    NA marine benthic biome           
#> 6 Branchiomma bo~ introduced range inc~    NA    NA Israeli part of the Mediterran~
#> 7 Branchiomma bo~ trophic guild            NA    NA suspension feeder              
#> 
#> [[10]]
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   species             measure                      min   max value                 
#>   <chr>               <chr>                      <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                 
#> 1 Branchiomma spongi~ body length                  100   100 mm                    
#> 2 Branchiomma spongi~ ecomorphological guild        NA    NA planktonic            
#> 3 Branchiomma spongi~ geographic distribution i~    NA    NA European waters (ERMS~
#> 4 Branchiomma spongi~ habitat is                    NA    NA marine benthic biome  
#> 5 Branchiomma spongi~ trophic guild                 NA    NA suspension feeder
```

Now you can easily access all the data on the pages and build up a per-species data frame as required.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Allan. Your contribution is very important for my current project. I appreciate your help and the time to spend it in my question. Have a nice week and weekend.